# How to call a method inside of a service in app.module - Angular

Tags: angular

I have a function in my service as follow:

```
export class DualLogonService {
  url: string;
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  saveURL(): void {
    this.url = this.router.url;
  }
}
```

**App.module**

```
import { DualLogonService } from './ dual-logon/dual-logon.service';
...
export function saveUrl(dualLogonService: DualLogonService, router: Router) {
  console.log(router.url);TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
  return dualLogonService.saveURL();//TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveURL' of undefined
}


{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  deps: [DualLogonService],
  useFactory: saveUrl,
  multi: true
}
```

If I do the following int the service, the function is accessible in the app.module, but I can't use the `this.router.url`:

```
export function saveURL() {
   this.url = this.router.url;
}
```

Comment: There is no router state when APP_INITIALIZER is called. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to get the url before the app runs you kno win the app initializer, I have updated my question

Comment: I'm not sure the router will be ready. You can give it a try and see if it has the URL, but if it doesn't just get it from the location.

Comment: @Reactgularn i updated my code, I'm using the router but it gives me an error ```Cannot read property 'url' of undefined``` it lets me call in on vscode but i think the router is ready. is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  //This function should be above the @ngModel decorator
  export function callSaveUrl(dualLogonService: DualLogonService) {
       //Do what you need here
       return (): Promise<any> => { 
         return dualLogonService.saveUrl();
        }
  }


 DualLogonService,
 { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,useFactory: callSaveUrl, deps: [DualLogonService], multi: true}
```

Try something like this, its untested but I think this is what you are looking for

Change your code from

```
{
 provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
 deps: [DualLogonService],
 useFactory: saveUrl,
 multi: true
}
```

To this

```
DualLogonService,
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER,useFactory: callSaveUrl, deps: [DualLogonService], multi: true}
```

Comment: I';m getting this error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveURL' of undefined```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time unfortunately  this line return ```dualLogonService.saveUrl();``` keeps giving me the same error

Comment: this-> ```DualLogonService,{...}``` the DuaLogon part gives me this error ```Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-```